# Golang xml key name conflicts

Tags: xml, go

I need to generate a complex xml file in order to load it into another system. Therefore, the tags and sequence of the tags cannot be changed as they must follow an exact format in order to correctly load it. I am currently using the encoding/xml package in golang to try and accomplish this.

The issue I'm running into is that I cannot have two tags that have the same name it seems. I am getting the following error: main.XMLDict field "Key1" with tag "key" conflicts with field "Key2" with tag "key". Below is my simplified code:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
    "os"
)

type XMLDict struct {
    XMLName xml.Name    `xml:"dict"`
    Key1    string      `xml:"key"`
    Data1   string      `xml:"data"`
    Key2    string      `xml:"key"`
    StringArray XMLStringArray
}

type XMLStringArray struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name    `xml:"array"̀`
    XMLString   []string `xml:"string"`
}

func main() {

    sa := make([]string, 3)
    sa[0] = "g"
    sa[1] = "h"
    sa[2] = "i"

    arr := XMLStringArray{
        XMLString: sa,
    }

    master := XMLDict{
        Key1: "Color",
        Data1: "Random data",
        Key2: "Curve",
        StringArray: arr,
    }

    output, err := xml.MarshalIndent(master, "  ", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }

    os.Stdout.Write(output)

    return 
}
```

Below is a sample from the XML file I need to generate:

```
     <dict>
            <key>Color</key>
            <data>
            BAtzdHJlYW10eXBlZIHoA4QBQISEhAdOU0NvbG9yAISECE5TT2Jq
            ZWN0AIWEAWMChARmZmZmg7oehT2DZmYmP4NmZiY/AYY=
            </data>
            <key>Curve</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Interpolation</key>
                <integer>5</integer>
                <key>Points</key>
                <array>
                    <string>{0, 0}</string>
                    <string>{0.05, 0.053871}</string>
                    <string>{0.1, 0.110555}</string>
                    <string>{0.15, 0.166793}</string>
                    <string>{0.2, 0.216919}</string>
                    <string>{0.3, 0.327703}</string>
                    <string>{0.4, 0.440897}</string>
                    <string>{0.5, 0.539322}</string>
                    <string>{0.6, 0.657477}</string>
                    <string>{0.7, 0.763339}</string>
                    <string>{0.75, 0.814082}</string>
                    <string>{0.8, 0.861097}</string>
                    <string>{0.85, 0.904147}</string>
                    <string>{0.9, 0.944079}</string>
                    <string>{0.95, 0.974036}</string>
                    <string>{0.98, 0.990085}</string>
                    <string>{1, 1}</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <key>Line Width</key>
            <real>0.0040000001899898052</real>
            <key>Points Diameter</key>
            <real>0.014999999664723873</real>
            <key>Precision</key>
            <real>9.9999997473787516e-05</real>
        </dict>
```

So, my question: 1)Is there a SIMPLE way to get around this still using the struct method of building the data and then generating the XML, 2)Is there a better way for me to build and generate this file rather than using stucts or 3)Am I simply doing something wrong?

Edit: Below is the input file as was requested:

```
"File created by Curve"
LGOROWLENGTH 3
#
# Curve4 Run Information
#
# Run: Run 1 - Calibration
# Based On: <none>
#
# Values in this file are 'Wanted'
#
# Gray Balance: On
#    reduced after 100%
#    until 100%
#    media white values: Measured
#    media aim points: -0.17 / 0.96
#
NUMBER_OF_FIELDS    6
BEGIN_DATA_FORMAT
SampleID    SAMPLE_NAME CMYK_C  CMYK_M  CMYK_Y  CMYK_K
END_DATA_FORMAT
NUMBER_OF_SETS 17
BEGIN_DATA
A0  "0.00"  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
A1  "5.00"  5.3871  5.1408  5.2761  5.5775
A2  "10.00" 11.0555 10.7418 10.6026 11.0702
A3  "15.00" 16.6793 16.3894 15.8763 16.7064
A4  "20.00" 21.6919 21.7968 21.0234 22.3956
A5  "30.00" 32.7703 32.7458 31.1841 33.6738
A6  "40.00" 44.0897 42.4801 40.0887 44.2966
A7  "50.00" 53.9322 54.2364 49.1680 54.8968
A8  "60.00" 65.7477 64.9423 59.1719 66.4696
A9  "70.00" 76.3339 75.4398 69.4943 77.1661
A10 "75.00" 81.4082 80.5957 75.1423 82.0637
A11 "80.00" 86.1097 84.9296 81.1298 86.7399
A12 "85.00" 90.4147 88.8039 86.7945 90.8142
A13 "90.00" 94.4079 92.6783 92.1110 94.2426
A14 "95.00" 97.4036 96.2097 96.6019 97.2088
A15 "98.00" 99.0085 98.5775 98.7747 98.9000
A16 "100.00"    100.0000    100.0000    100.0000    100.0000
END_DATA
```

Comment: This can easily be done in Powershell.  Can you post sample of input file?

Comment: "Am I simply doing something wrong?" The xml you need to generate is poorly modeled.  Instead <key> elements that are meant to correspond to immediately following value items, the key should be the element name eg `<Color>...</Color><Curve><Interpolation>5</Interpolation>...</Curve>`.  If you're stuck with that illogical XML model, you'll have to write your own marshal logic to produce it

Comment: It is a computer generated file. Right now, someone is manually taking the input file I posted and then entering in those values which genreates the xml. The software itself is very slow and is VERY time consuming. I am therefore building an in-between software which will act as a hot folder to pick up any generated files and simply output the xml into a different hot folder to remove the manual work. Therefore, my input data and my output data are quite fixed other than the fact that the length of the number of <dict> elements I have in an array (the sample code only shows 1) can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions to do this with XML custom [marshalers](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Marshaler) I think; here's my attempt.

First, inside your root `<dict>`, it seems to always be a "list" of items like this:

```xml
<key>a-string</key>
<data|integer|real|array|dict>a-value</data|integer|real|array|dict>

<key>another-string</key>
<data|integer|real|array|dict>another-value</data|integer|real|array|dict>
```

To represent each of these, we can define a `KeyValue` struct, with a `Value` just being an interface to represent anything it can hold (`data`, `integer`, ...)

```golang
type KeyValue struct {
    Key   string
    Value Value
}

type Value interface {
    getXMLName() string // this will return data, integer, array, etc, depending on the implementation
}
```

Then, we can implement `Value` with the different types provided in your example:

```golang
type ValueData struct {
    Data string `xml:",chardata"`
}

func (v ValueData) getXMLName() string { return "data" }

type ValueInteger struct {
    Integer int `xml:",chardata"`
}

func (v ValueInteger) getXMLName() string { return "integer" }

type ValueStringArray struct {
    Array []string `xml:"string"`
}

func (v ValueStringArray) getXMLName() string { return "array" }

type ValueReal struct {
    Real float64 `xml:",chardata"`
}

func (v ValueReal) getXMLName() string { return "real" }
```

Inside the XML tags, `chardata` is used to avoid including an additional level in our XML document; for `ValueStringArray`, we use `string` because your items are named like this.

Finally, to allow recursion (`dict` inside `dict`), we can also define this struct:

```golang
type ValueDict struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name `xml:"dict"`
    KeysValues []KeyValue
}

func (v ValueDict) getXMLName() string { return "dict" }
```

Once everything done, we can just implement a single custom marshaler:

```golang
func (kv KeyValue) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, _ xml.StartElement) error {
    if err := e.EncodeElement(kv.Key, xml.StartElement{Name: xml.Name{Local: "key"}}); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := e.EncodeElement(kv.Value, xml.StartElement{Name: xml.Name{Local: kv.Value.getXMLName()}}); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

This will allow to generate items like:

```xml
<key>Line Width</key>
<real>0.004000000189989805</real>
```

The name of the tag (here `real`) is based on what the `getXMLName()` method return.

Finally, you can define your Go struct and marshal like this:

```golang
master := ValueDict{
    KeysValues: []KeyValue{
        {
            Key: "Color",
            Value: ValueData{
                Data: "BAtzdHJlYW10eXBlZIHoA4QBQISEhAdOU0NvbG9yAISECE5TT2JqZWN0AIWEAWMChARmZmZmg7oehT2DZmYmP4NmZiY/AYY=",
            },
        },
        {
            Key: "Curve",
            Value: ValueDict{
                KeysValues: []KeyValue{
                    {
                        Key: "Interpolation",
                        Value: ValueInteger{
                            Integer: 5,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        Key: "Points",
                        Value: ValueStringArray{
                            Array: []string{
                                "{0, 0}",
                                "{0.05, 0.053871}",
                                "{0.1, 0.110555}",
                                "{0.15, 0.166793}",
                                "{0.2, 0.216919}",
                                "{0.3, 0.327703}",
                                "{0.4, 0.440897}",
                                "{0.5, 0.539322}",
                                "{0.6, 0.657477}",
                                "{0.7, 0.763339}",
                                "{0.75, 0.814082}",
                                "{0.8, 0.861097}",
                                "{0.85, 0.904147}",
                                "{0.9, 0.944079}",
                                "{0.95, 0.974036}",
                                "{0.98, 0.990085}",
                                "{1, 1}",
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        {
            Key: "Line Width",
            Value: ValueReal{
                Real: 0.0040000001899898052,
            },
        },
        {
            Key: "Points Diameter",
            Value: ValueReal{
                Real: 0.014999999664723873,
            },
        },
        {
            Key: "Precision",
            Value: ValueReal{
                Real: 9.9999997473787516e-05,
            },
        },
    },
}

output, err := xml.MarshalIndent(master, "  ", "    ")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
}

os.Stdout.Write(output)
```

This will print exactly what you have in your sample XML provided in your question.

You can test the full code in Go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/k8cEIywx3UB.

The main advantage of this solution is:

- we only need to implement a single custom XML marshaler
- this can be easily extended if you have other structures in your XML doc (let's say a boolean, we can create a `ValueBool` implementing `Value`)

Comment: Wow. This is pretty awesome. I'll need some time to fully digest this as the actual xml file I need to generate is much larger and the sample shown is one <dict> that is actually nested and there is an array of those as well. Based on the fact that you have been able to generate the needed xml, I should be able to take these concepts to complete it. I did note that golang doesn't support self closing tags though </false> and </true> are in the xml that I need to generate and assumed I would need to manually insert those afterwards using some form of string manipulation. Thank you for answer!!

Comment: You should be able to extend my solution pretty easily I think (thanks to the interface), so even if you have nested elements inside nested elements, it's just a matter of nesting `ValueDict` or `ValueStringArray` (or whatever you need) inside other `ValueDict`s. About self-closing tags, you're absolutely right, [Go doesn't support it yet](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/59710), but once you get familiar with custom marshalers you can do pretty much everything you want :) Glad my answer helped you.

Comment: Yep, I've been working on it and what you gave me makes sense. Your answer also gave me a lot of insight into how this package works that I couldn't find elsewhere. I've accepted the answer and GREATLY appreciate your time.